# Growth of Partition function

Tags: combinatorics

**Question**
Let the number of partitions be given by the function $p(n)$,i.e. the number of ways of writing the integer $n$ as a sum of positive integers. Prove that that if $g$ is any polnoymial function in $n$, then there exists an integer N such that $g(n) < p(n)$ for all $n>N$. Do not use the asymptotic Hardy-Ramanujan formula.

---

**Attempts**

It would seem to me to use $$\text{lim}_{n->\infty} \frac{g(n)}{p(n)} = 0$$ But I'm not sure if I can't assume any form for $p(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

To show that the partition function is large, it suffices to produce many partitions; you don't need to count all of them. Fix a positive integer $m$ that is greater than the degree of $g$. Consider only the partitions of the form 
$$\underbrace{1+\dots+1}_{a_1 \text{ times}}+\underbrace{2+\dots+2}_{a_2 \text{ times}} + \dots +\underbrace{m+\dots+m}_{a_m \text{ times}} + \left(n-\sum_{k=1}^m ka_k\right)$$
Any choice of nonnegative integers $a_1,\dots,a_m$ less than $n/m^2$ results in a legal partition, because 
$$\sum_{k=1}^m ka_k <  m\cdot m\cdot n/m^2=n$$
All the partitions of the above form are distinct. Hence, the total number of partitions satisfies 
$$p(n)\ge \left(\frac{n}{m^2}\right)^m$$
The conclusion $g(n)/p(n)\to 0$ follows.